# Forma rápida de buscar primeiro registro

Tags: php, mysql

Estou realizando a seguinte consulta no MySQL:

```
select id from positions
where device_id = {$device_id} and p1 IS NOT NULL
order by time desc limit 1
```

Mas a consulta está demorando muito, pois a tabela em questão é gigante (90GB).

As colunas `id`, `device_id` e `time` estão indexadas, mas mesmo assim demora muito.

Executei:

```
EXPLAIN select id from TABLE
where device_id = $x and P IS NOT NULL order by TIME desc limit 1
```

E o resultado foi:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys            | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | positions | index | device_id,p1,device_id_2 | time | 9       | NULL |  306 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: Boa Tarde amigo, essas 3 colunas ja possuem índices  **id**, **device_id** e **time**.

Comment: Então, tem outros índices que poderiam ajudar nessa query específica se existissem. O problema é o impacto que podem ter no resto da sua aplicação.

Comment: Entendo amigo obrigado.

dentro da mesma situação, a columa **time** é timestamp numérico, a melhor forma de buscar o primeiro registro é via **ORDER BY** mesmo? ou teria outra forma?

Comment: Depende. Já que a query está usando o índice da coluna time, experimente colocar uma nova condição sobre essa coluna, por exemplo filtrando os registros a partir do dia ou hora atual. Isso pode resolver o problema de performance.